# Color combination background change android studio kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, user-input, background-color

I'm a beginner and I want to make an app that combine basic colors depending on user input. For example input 1 = red, and input 2 = yellow, click combine button then the background will change to color orange. (using kotlin)

I have no idea how to do it but here is my progress

```
package com.example.calculator

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var b1=findViewById(R.id.combine) as Button
        var e1=findViewById(R.id.color1enter) as EditText
        var e2=findViewById(R.id.color2enter) as EditText

        b1.setOnClickListener{
            if e1 = "red" and e2 = "yellow"{
                make background orange
            }
        }
    }
}
```

input 1 = red
input 2 = yellow
background changes to color orange

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to change the background of the app, once you define the colors then you can call the layout background change in the button click.

Example

```
// set button 1 with its id
    button1 = findViewById(R.id.btVar1);
     
    // set button 2 with its id
    button2 = findViewById(R.id.btVar2);
     
    // set relative layout with its id
    relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.rlVar1);
     
    // onClick function for button 1
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // set the color to relative layout
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.cool);
        }
    });
     
    // onClick function for button 2
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // set the color to relative layout
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.warm);
        }
    });
```

This is based off two buttons as an example. If you want all of this on one button then you can use `if statement` in the click event of one button to change the colors on the background.

There is several ways you can achieve this. But this is a great example. To combine the colors you will have set the palette color as well